# When I put IMEI no on textbox it fill all combo boxes with their relavant values like brand

Tags: c#, combobox

How to fill the Combo boxes value, when a text box is filled with some value or when I put IMEI no on text box it fill combo boxes according to its relevant fields.

I've try this

```
cmbSupplierName.DataSource = t.Tables[0];
cmbSupplierName.DisplayMember = "SupplierName";
cmbSupplierName.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are using (**Windows Forms** or **WPF**), read about **data bindings**. In general, you'll have to implement a separate class for this data and bind collection of its' items to `Combobox`es